# How do you make an element in a SwiftUI loop full screen? Like Apple's, App of the day

Tags: ios, animation, scrollview, swiftui, offset

[Here's a gif of what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9TzT.gif)

Trying a bunch of things here, like offset and zIndex but they don't change the position, I'm looking for something like absolute position in css to make the card full screen.

```
    var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("")
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
    .frame(height: show ? UIScreen.main.bounds.height : 200)
    .zIndex(show ? 1 : 0)
    .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    .cornerRadius(show ? 0 : 20)
    .padding(show ? 0 : 30)
    .offset(y: show ? 0 : viewState.height)
    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `GeometryReader` instead, combining with `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var show = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack { Text("") }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: self.show ? geo.size.height : 200)
                .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .cornerRadius(self.show ? 0 : 20)
                .padding(self.show ? 0 : 30)
                .offset(y: self.show ? 0 : 0)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.show.toggle()
            }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Single View[1]

---

**Note That** This was just an answer to the original question and original provided code, If you like to embed the card in another way like using `ScrollView`, you should consider some changes to the original code of course. For example:

```
struct CardView: View {
    @Binding var show: Bool

    var body: some View {

        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .cornerRadius(self.show ? 0 : 20)
            .padding(self.show ? 0 : 30)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))
    }
}

extension Int: Identifiable { public var id: Int { self } }

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var show = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<1) { item in
                        CardView(show: self.$show)
                            .frame(height: self.show ? geo.size.height : 200)
                        .onTapGesture { self.show.toggle() }


                    }
                }
            }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

[image: Inside a scrollView]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @mojtaba-hosseini! I can replicate your animation with one card, but when it's a ScrollView with a loop of cards, it doesn't apply, any thoughts?

`ScrollView {
                            ForEach() { item in
                                Card(item: item)
                            }
                        }`

The card component doesn't animate full screen in this case

Comment: [Output for me when in a loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o8RT.gif).

Comment: Because geometry represents the parent view. When you embed it in another view, you should consider that geometry data changes accordingly. I have added another example for you. Hope it will giude you the achieve what you need.